# What's the name of this array data structure?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Have an idea for a data structure that would be useful for a research project and want to see if it already has a name or STL equivalent:

Create a sparse array of size `n` as an array of `sqrt(n)` pointers.

To insert an item at `i`, go to the pointer at `i/sqrt(n)`. If that pointer is `null`, assign it to a new array of size `sqrt(n)`. Insert your item in the new array at position `i mod sqrt(n)`.

The advantage is simple: it allows you to create a large array that initially takes only `O(sqrt(n))` space. You can access any element in constant time, and it allows you to fill portions of the array without needing to allocate space for all `n` positions.

This may already be used for hash-table bucketing, and I have another application in mind (memoizing contigs in a very large DNA sequence). My question is: is there a name for this? Any common implementation I can use?

Comment: For those looking for an implementation, Google very nearly does this with what is called a sparse table, except using constant sized buckets instead of buckets proportional to table size. http://google-sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/implementation.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This data structure is closely related to the [hashed array tree (HAT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashed_array_tree) data structure.  A hashed array tree is structured like what you've described above - you have a top-level array of size √n, where each entry is a pointer to an array with √n elements.  This makes insertions and lookups reasonably fast and has only O(√n) memory overhead compared with the O(n) memory overhead of a traditional dynamic array.

Your structure differs from the HAT in a few ways.  For starters, your structure does not appear to have a way to grow the structure if you need more space, whereas the HAT is designed to be growable.  Additionally, your structure allows for random insertions, whereas the HAT is designed for sequential insertions.  That said, there's no fundamental reason that the HAT has to behave this way, so you can think of your data structure as a slight modification on the HAT.  In fact, you might want to look at how the HAT grows in order to make your data structure support growth.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think HAT is what I am looking for - it's obviously more refined than what I had in mind, but I expected that would be the case for whatever turned up.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I would call that *a square matrix with row vectors.* If not fully populated, it's a *sparse* square matrix with row vectors.<sup>1.</sup>

There are two optimizations at work here. The first is the sparse memory allocation, and the second is the [strength reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction) of the row subscript calculation. This optimization is probably not quite so important with superscaler CPU's executing instructions out-of-order, and in an age where compilers routinely do global flow optimizations.

But it does allow row indexing via a pointer dereference rather than a multiply by the row size.

---

<sup>1. However, in numerical analysis, a sparse matrix is one that's mostly zeroes, and so a sparse data structure formally has the same definition. In this case, it's more of a *partial* data structure, but there just aren't, to my knowledge, accepted terms for these things.</sup>

Comment: Yeah it's a super weird description though. Probably someone trying to confuse his students :-)

Comment: It's a hash table with a very simple has function that only works on ints.

Comment: @ArgumentNullException Calling a dynamic two dimensional array a hash table quite a stretch.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Dynamic Hash Table then?  The only reason I wouldn't call this a hash table is because there will never ever be a collision.

Comment: @ArgumentNullException It's not really a hash if the function a 1:1 mapping. Plus I would seriously never call this anything else than a dynamic (two dimensional) array, OK, maybe dynamic sparse array.

Comment: I don't agree with your "strength reduction" argument. The public interface of this data structure takes a single index, not a row/column pair; the row subscript calculation is only necessary because you've first performed the inverse operation.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I agree.  Which is what I meant when I said no collision.  In any case, it's probably an instructor's way of encouraging his/her students to come up with their own data structure.

Comment: Or to put it another way: if you use a single (flat) array, indexing is the minimal `base+index*element_size`. If you split the array up, you decrease memory use, but you do not decrease the cost of indexing into the array, you *increase* it because now you need a divmod operation to split the index into row and column indices (and you pay the extra cost of an indirection which could easily exceed the index calculation cost by a large margin).

Comment: @JB, good point. Unless the internal interface is exposed and used, it's externally a 1D vector and the row vectors are just part of the implementation. I suppose I could argue that *to the middleware* the object actually constructed is a 2D array with strength-reduced indexing, but that would require a bit of twisted logic. So perhaps I should have said "a sparse *vector* but it's unclear whether we were supposed to describe the abstraction or the implementation.

Comment: Its absolutely not a sparse matrix

Comment: Considering the arguments above, this data structure could just be a more memory efficient implementation of an stl vector.

Comment: Actually I wondered if STL vectors already did something like this internally. I'm a little surprised this isn't a data structure with an established name given how obvious it feels. In answer to Let_Me_Be: sorry about the weird description, I'm actually just a graduate researcher looking for literature on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's an array of buckets.

Java's hastable implementation is such a "bucket based hashtable".
Here a graphic for such [buckets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

There are other structures like quad trees, that too uses such buckets.

In your case you have sqrt(n) buckets.

Answer (score 0):

I call it a segmented array.  I use these when mapping handles to pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It is also quite similar to the first level of a [Van Emde Boas Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree).

A Van Emde Boas Tree stores sqrt(n) pointers at the first level, but has additional trees at lower levels instead of just a simple array as in this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a data structure per se. It seems that this technique could be utilize in other collection type data structures.

Edit:
It's definitely a mechanism for storing or organizing data, but I've always associated a data structure with storage/retrieval (read/write) mechanisms.

Comment: Why doesn't this count as a data structure?

Comment: I'm just thinking you can use it to implement a vector, list, or what have you.